# Big-O / smal-o for perturbed matrix-inversion: What is $(A_n + \mathcal O_n(n^{-\alpha}))^{-1}$?

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics, matrix-calculus, perturbation-theory

Let $\alpha > 0$ and for each natural number, let $B_n$ be a square matrix $B_n = \mathcal O(n^{-\alpha})$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Suppose $A_n$ is ineverible for every $n$ and $A_n \rightarrow A$ (invertible).

## Question

What is the order of $(A_n + B_n)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: $(A+B)^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}BA^{-1}+A^{-1}BA^{-1}BA^{-1}-A^{-1}BA^{-1}BA^{-1}BA^{-1}+\cdots$, as you can verify by multiplying by $(A+B)$. Does that help?

Comment: Hum, this seems to imply $(A_n + B_n)^{-1} = A_n^{-1} + \mathcal O(n^{-\alpha})$.